# How to calculate 2^n-1 efficiently without overflow?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to calculate 2<sup>n</sup>-1 for a 64bit integer value.
What I currently do is this

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++) r|=1<<i;
```

and I wonder if there is more elegant way to do it.
The line is in an inner loop, so I need it to be fast.

I thought of

```
  r=(1ULL<<n)-1;
```

but it doesn't work for `n=64`, because `<<` is only defined 
for values of `n` up to 63.

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all your answers and comments.
Here is a little table with the solutions that I tried and liked best.
Second column is time in seconds of my (completely unscientific) benchmark.

```
    
r=N2MINUSONE_LUT[n];            3.9 lookup table = fastest, answer by aviraldg
r =n?~0ull>>(64 - n):0ull;      5.9 fastest without LUT, comment by Christoph
r=(1ULL<<n)-1;                  5.9 Obvious but WRONG!   
r =(n==64)?-1:(1ULL<<n)-1;      7.0 Short, clear and quite fast, answer by Gabe
r=((1ULL<<(n/2))<<((n+1)/2))-1; 8.2 Nice, w/o spec. case, answer by drawnonward
r=(1ULL<<n-1)+((1ULL<<n-1)-1);  9.2 Nice, w/o spec. case, answer by David Lively
r=pow(2, n)-1;               99.0 Just for comparison
for(i=0; i<n; i++) r|=1<<i;   123.7 My original solution = lame
```

I accepted

```
r =n?~0ull>>(64 - n):0ull;
```

as answer because it's in my opinion the most elegant solution.
It was [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48015/christoph) who came up with it at first, but unfortunately he only posted it in a
[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032951/how-to-calculate-2n-1-efficiently-without-overflow/3033004#3033004). [Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) added a really nice rationale, so I accept his answer instead. Because I liked [Aviral Dasgupta's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152873/aviral-dasgupta) lookup table [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032951/how-to-calculate-2n-1-efficiently-without-overflow/3032977#3032977) it got 50 reputation points via a bounty.

Comment: yes since 1<<64 is 0; e.g. on 4 bits: 0001 << 1 = 0010, 0001 << 2 = 0100, 0001 << 3 = 1000, 0001 << 4 = 0000 (bit flies away or in some processor bit register)

Comment: Just for comparison: My for-loop solution took 120s for my specific problem.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: If 1<<64 was 0 everything would be fine, because 0ULL-1ULL=18446744073709551615ULL in modular arithmetic. This is even standard behaviour and you and rely on this.
The problem is that the result of 1<<64 is implementation dependant. On my machine, with my compiler 1ULL<<64 results in 1.

Comment: if speed is your problem and it is not a problem to stick into hardware dependent optimization, I would write it in asm, where you by the way can also "access" more bit ops that _could_ be useful (in this case maybe not anyway)

Comment: naa throw away C then, do it with few asm lines, consider it like a per processor optimization (you have to rewrite the code for other processor if you need porting)

Comment: @ShinTakezou: I'm not sure if asm solves the problem.
Do you know how shl n,64 behaves? I'd bet it has the same problems as the C solution. I couldn't find a resource where the overflow behaviour of shl is documented though.
Any pointers welcome.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: There is no easy asm solution on Intel. From the documentation of the shl instruction:                                   "The count is masked to 5 bits (or 6 bits
if in 64-bit mode and REX.W is used). The count range is limited to 0 to 31 (or 63 if
64-bit mode and REX.W is used)."

Comment: @Lud... you're right, I've experimented and found that when shifting with a num > 31 it let a 1 "enter" from right!! (I've tried with 32bit since I've not a 64bit machine); but if 1 << 32 or more can do 0, the it can be fixed anyway; btw, the solution ~-(A) | A gives "-1" for n > 31; just in case of curiousity I am adding my test in the answer

Comment: @Thanks for your asm answer, I will have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @ShinTakezou: See comment to your answer.

Comment: @Ludwig Weinzierl done; if performance are an issue, the lookup table of course performs better as your test shows; about my strange solution, that artifice is not needed at all if the case n>63 is treated apart someway,i.e. one can stick to the `?:` solution with is also clearer as you've already noticed; on processor where shifting left > of the width gives 0, it'd be simpler:)

Comment: I'll also point out if you didn't notice that the `pow(2, n)-1` solution will provide you with incorrect results as a double is not sufficient precision to represent some of the bigger integers (like the `n=64` one for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like aviraldg answer best.
Just to get rid of the `ULL' stuff etc in C99 I would do

```
static inline uint64_t n2minusone(unsigned n) {
   return n ? (~(uint64_t)0) >> (64u - n) : 0;
}
```

To see that this is valid

- an uint64_t is guaranteed to have a width of exactly 64 bit
- the bit negation of that `zero of type uint64_t' has thus exactly
   64 one bits
- right shift of an unsigned value is guaranteed to be a logical
   shift, so everything is filled with zeros from the left
- shift with a value equal or greater to the width is undefined, so
   yes you have to do at least one conditional to be sure of your result
- an inline function (or alternatively a cast to uint64_t if you
   prefer) makes this type safe; an `unsigned long long` may
   well be an 128 bit wide value in the future
- a `static inline` function should be seamlessly
   inlined in the caller without any overhead

Comment: Nice explanation and I agree.
While aviraldg supplied the LUT solution your solution is basically Christoph's comment to Gabe's answer.
It's also the second fastest after aviraldgs LUT.

Comment: Sure it must be slower, since it has the extra conditional. Can't compare the speed of a correct version and an incorrect one, can't you?
BTW, your speed measures, I didn't see anything on this page where you define it, what compiler, cpu etc you use. The results will be much dependent on this.

Comment: aviraldgs LUT solution is also correct, so the comparison is valid.

Answer (score 31):

[Use a lookup table.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) (Generated by your present code.) This is ideal, since the number of values is small, and you know the results already.

```
/* lookup table: n -> 2^n-1 -- do not touch */
const static uint64_t N2MINUSONE_LUT[] = {
0x0,
0x1,
0x3,
0x7,
0xf,
0x1f,
0x3f,
0x7f,
0xff,
0x1ff,
0x3ff,
0x7ff,
0xfff,
0x1fff,
0x3fff,
0x7fff,
0xffff,
0x1ffff,
0x3ffff,
0x7ffff,
0xfffff,
0x1fffff,
0x3fffff,
0x7fffff,
0xffffff,
0x1ffffff,
0x3ffffff,
0x7ffffff,
0xfffffff,
0x1fffffff,
0x3fffffff,
0x7fffffff,
0xffffffff,
0x1ffffffff,
0x3ffffffff,
0x7ffffffff,
0xfffffffff,
0x1fffffffff,
0x3fffffffff,
0x7fffffffff,
0xffffffffff,
0x1ffffffffff,
0x3ffffffffff,
0x7ffffffffff,
0xfffffffffff,
0x1fffffffffff,
0x3fffffffffff,
0x7fffffffffff,
0xffffffffffff,
0x1ffffffffffff,
0x3ffffffffffff,
0x7ffffffffffff,
0xfffffffffffff,
0x1fffffffffffff,
0x3fffffffffffff,
0x7fffffffffffff,
0xffffffffffffff,
0x1ffffffffffffff,
0x3ffffffffffffff,
0x7ffffffffffffff,
0xfffffffffffffff,
0x1fffffffffffffff,
0x3fffffffffffffff,
0x7fffffffffffffff,
0xffffffffffffffff,
};
```

Comment: This is actually quite useful, since the values are known ahead of time.

Comment: might look less mysterious if values were defined in hex

Comment: Wow, thanks for the table. I did a quick test and it's almost twice as fast as the "special case n=64" solution (3.9s for my specific problem).

Comment: And make the table static const, since it's not going to change. :)

Comment: The `ull` suffix is unnecessary for hexadecimal integer literals.

Comment: When is the `ull` suffix necessary?

Comment: 67 lines of code instead of 1? If a LUT is necessary for speed (which is possible, but the effect of and on the cache is hard to measure), why is statically declaring it better than initialising with code?

Comment: @paul : It isn't. Nor have I said so. The OP's asked for speed and elegance. Those don't exactly come packaged with readability.

Comment: might I suggest as a comment `/* lookup table: n -> 2^n-1 -- do not touch */` instead.

Answer (score 25):

How about a simple `r = (n == 64) ? -1 : (1ULL<<n)-1;`?

Comment: I like that, it's concise, easy to understand and reasonably fast (7.0 s for my specific problem).

Comment: `n ? ~0ull >> (64 - n) : 0ull` is equivalent and *might* be faster because there's only a single 64bit op

Comment: Pedantically, I prefer ~0 to -1, since -1 implies (to me, not the compiler) that you're working with signed integers.

Comment: @Christoph you're a hacker. It's 5.9s vs 7.0s for the original.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to get the max value just before overflow with a given number of bits, try

```
r=(1ULL << n-1)+((1ULL<<n-1)-1);
```

By splitting the shift into two parts (in this case, two 63 bit shifts, since 2^64=2*2^63), subtracting 1 and then adding the two results together, you should be able to do the calculation without overflowing the 64 bit data type.

Comment: David, you win a special price for the most elegant solution. It's a little bit slower than the "special case n=64" solution (9.2s for my specific problem).

Comment: @Ludwig, you might be able to speed it up by calculating 1ULL<<n-1 once in a temporary, if the compiler isn't doing it for you already.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (n > 64 || n < 0)
  return undefined...

if (n == 64)
  return 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL;

return (1ULL << n) - 1;
```

Comment: That sure is a `FULL` 64 bit integer :P (I usually change the case of the suffix from the hex number to eliminate confusion)

Answer (score 4):

The only problem is that your expression isn't defined for n=64? Then special-case that one value.

```
(n == 64 ? 0ULL : (1ULL << n)) - 1ULL
```

Answer (score 4):

Shifting 1 << 64 in a 64 bit integer yields 0, so no need to compute anything for n > 63; shifting should be enough fast

```
r = n < 64 ? (1ULL << n) - 1 : 0;
```

But if you are trying this way to know the max value a N bit unsigned integer can have, you change 0 into the known value treating n == 64 as a special case (and you are not able to give a result for n > 64 on hardware with 64bit integer unless you use a multiprecision/bignumber library).

Another approach with bit tricks

```
~-(1ULL << (n-1) ) | (1ULL << (n-1))
```

check if it can be semplified... of course, n>0

**EDIT**

Tests I've done

```
__attribute__((regparm(0))) unsigned int calcn(int n)
{
  register unsigned int res;
  asm(
    "  cmpl $32, %%eax\n"
    "  jg   mmno\n"
    "  movl $1, %%ebx\n"      // ebx = 1
    "  subl $1, %%eax\n"      // eax = n - 1
    "  movb %%al, %%cl\n"     // because of only possible shll reg mode
    "  shll %%cl, %%ebx\n"    // ebx = ebx << eax
    "  movl %%ebx, %%eax\n"   // eax = ebx
    "  negl %%ebx\n"          // -ebx
    "  notl %%ebx\n"          // ~-ebx
    "  orl  %%ebx, %%eax\n"   // ~-ebx | ebx
    "  jmp  mmyes\n"
    "mmno:\n"
    "  xor %%eax, %%eax\n"
    "mmyes:\n"
    :
    "=eax" (res):
    "eax" (n):
    "ebx", "ecx", "cc"
    );
  return res;
}

#define BMASK(X) (~-(1ULL << ((X)-1) ) | (1ULL << ((X)-1)))
int main()
{
  int n = 32; //...
  printf("%08X\n", BMASK(n));
  printf("%08X %d %08X\n", calcn(n), n&31, BMASK(n&31));
  return 0;
}
```

Output with n = 32 is -1 and -1, while n = 52 yields "-1" and 0xFFFFF, casually 52&31 = 20 and of course n = 20 gives 0xFFFFF...

**EDIT2** now the asm code produces 0 for n > 32 (since I am on a 32 bit machine), but at this point the `a ? b : 0` solution with the BMASK is clearer and I doubt the asm solution is too much faster (if speed is a so big concern the table idea could be the faster).

Comment: Thanks for your solution Shin. The problem is that 1<<64 is not 0.  If 1<<64 was 0 everything would be fine, because 0ULL-1ULL=18446744073709551615ULL in modular arithmetic. This is even standard behaviour and you and rely on this. The problem is that the result of 1<<64 is implementation dependant. On my machine, with my compiler 1ULL<<64 results in 1.

Comment: a `n<64 ? calcn(n) : 0` would solve anyway then? (with calcn(n) anything from asm code to ~-(A)|(A) or alike)?

Comment: As promised I had a look at your code. I don't get why you do ~-(1ULL << (n-1) ) | (1ULL << (n-1)). I seems overly complicated while it doesn't solve the original problem (that I have to special case either 0 or 64). Am I missing something?

Comment: No, missing nothing but ~-A|A is to obtain a mask "upto" the bit "marked" by the position of the only 1 bit in A (obtained with A << n-1 that works for n=64, so that n==64 needs no to be special case anymore, but n>64 gives no 0 as you'd like),since you can't do 2^64-1,but ~-(2^63)|(2^63) is ok. Basically you still need ?: to return 0 for n>64, while my prev comment should be corrected into `(n<=64 && n>0) ? calcn(n) : 0`. Sorry, no better ideas at the moment. Currently the table could be the faster way, but still need checking for n > of the num of elements in table.

Comment: P.S. yes it's overly complicated as expression, it seems simpler `n>=64 ? 0 : (1ULL << n)-1`; but here a real subtraction must be performed, while "negating" could be a little bit more performant of subtracting, in asm, __but__ `neg r0; not r0; or r1, r1, r0` instead of `sub r1, r1, 1`, and there's a n-1 anyway, and the shift also (in common), so my solution has anyway more instructions and so it is yes, overly complicated and not efficient :( (but ~-A|A looks very fine to me:)

Answer (score 4):

Since you've asked for an elegant way to do it:

```
const uint64_t MAX_UINT64 = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
#define N2MINUSONE(n) ((MAX_UINT64>>(64-(n))))
```

Comment: Of the methods I've seen, I like this the best.  Deterministic.  No branching.  Small footprint.  Portable.  Original thinking.  Kudos!

Comment: Unfortunately it gives a wrong result for n=0. 
Your lookup table has 65 entries (not 64) and that's correct because I asked for results from 2^0-1 up to 2^64-1. The right operand shift has only 64 possible meaningful values. That's why I (now) think that a solution with a single shift is not possible.

Comment: @ludwig : Looking at the comments above, I noticed that Cristoph's solution is exactly the same, apart from the fact that he's special casing 0.

Comment: You left out the special case (which is important) but otherwise you are right. It's the fastest (except for the LUT) and probably most elegant solution so far.

Answer (score 3):

I hate it that (a) `n << 64` is undefined and (b) on the popular Intel hardware shifting by word size is a no-op.

You have three ways to go here:

1. Lookup table.  I recommend against this because of the memory traffic, plus you will write a lot of code to maintain the memory traffic.
2. Conditional branch.  Check if `n` is equal to the word size (`8 * sizeof(unsigned long long)`), if so, return `~(unsigned long long)0`, otherwise shift and subtract as usual.
3. Try to get clever with arithmetic.  For example, in real numbers `2^n = 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-1)`, and you can exploit this identity to make sure you never use a power equal to the word size.  But you had better be very sure that `n` is never zero, because if it is, this identity cannot be expressed in the integers, and shifting left by -1 is likely to bite you in the ass.

I personally would go with the conditional branch—it is the hardest to screw up, manifestly handles all reasonable cases of `n`, and with modern hardware the likelihood of a branch misprediction is small.  Here's what I do in my real code:

```
/* What makes things hellish is that C does not define the effects of
   a 64-bit shift on a 64-bit value, and the Intel hardware computes
   shifts mod 64, so that a 64-bit shift has the same effect as a
   0-bit shift.  The obvious workaround is to define new shift functions 
   that can shift by 64 bits. */

static inline uint64_t shl(uint64_t word, unsigned bits) {
  assert(bits <= 64);
  if (bits == 64)
    return 0;
  else
    return word << bits;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you are seeing is caused because `(1<<n)-1` is evaluated as `(1<<(n%64))-1` on some chips.  Especially if n is or can be optimized as a constant.

Given that, there are many minor variations you can do.  For example:

```
((1ULL<<(n/2))<<((n+1)/2))-1;
```

You will have to measure to see if that is faster then special casing 64:

```
(n<64)?(1ULL<<n)-1:~0ULL;
```

Comment: @drawnonward: (1<<(64%64))-1=(1<<0)-1=0, Hmm, could be right. Works and is nearly as fast as the '64 special case' solution, I measured 8.3s.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that in C each bit-shifting operation has to shift by less bits than there are bits in the operand (otherwise, the behavior is undefined). However, nobody prohibits you from doing the shift in two consecutive steps

```
r = ((1ULL << (n - 1)) << 1) - 1;
```

I.e. shift by `n - 1` bits first and then make an extra 1 bit shift. In this case, of course, you have to handle `n == 0` situation in a special way, if that is a valid input in your case.

In any case, it is better than your `for` cycle. The latter is basically the same idea but taken to the extreme for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ub = universe in bits = lg(U):
high(v) = v >> (Ub / 2)
low(v) = v & ((~0) >> (Ub - Ub / 2))  // Deal with overflow and with Ub even or odd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit integer division inaccuracy and use the modulo of the exponent to ensure you always shift in the range [0, `(sizeof(uintmax_t) * CHAR_BIT) - 1`] to create a universal `pow2i` function for integers of the largest supported native word size, however, this can easily be tweaked to support arbitrary word sizes.

I honestly don't get why this isn't just the implementation in hardware for bit shift overflows.

```
#include <limits.h>
static inline uintmax_t pow2i(uintmax_t exponent) {
    #define WORD_BITS  ( sizeof(uintmax_t) * CHAR_BIT )
    return ((uintmax_t) 1) << (exponent / WORD_BITS) << (exponent % WORD_BITS);
    #undef WORD_BITS
}
```

From there, you can calculate `pow2i(n) - 1`.